# Git push heroku master not deploying app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I was developing an app on Ruby on Rails. I was successfully able to add, commit and push it to heroku using

```
$ git push heroku master
```

Later I switched back to previous commit using

```
git reset --head Head^1
```

I did all the changes and pushed it back to heroku. When I opened my app, no changes were made and it was still on a previous version. Changes are being shown in my localhost but not on the server.

I restarted my app using

```
$ heroku restart -app app-name
```

And here is the output when I restarted:

```
Restarting dynos... done
```

This is the output when I pushed my app to heroku after restarting

```
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 435 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.2
remote:        Using rake 10.4.2
remote:        Using minitest 5.5.1
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.4
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile 0.6.2
remote:        Using rack 1.6.0
remote:        Using mime-types 2.4.3
remote:        Using arel 6.0.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.3.0
remote:        Using bcrypt 3.1.10
remote:        Using sass 3.4.13
remote:        Using net-ssh 2.9.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using ffi 1.9.8
remote:        Using tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Using hike 1.2.3
remote:        Using multi_json 1.10.1
remote:        Using kgio 2.9.3
remote:        Using libv8 3.16.14.7
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.0
remote:        Using subexec 0.2.3
remote:        Using pg 0.18.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Using raindrops 0.13.0
remote:        Using ref 1.0.5
remote:        Using dropbox-sdk 1.6.4
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using warden 1.2.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.3
remote:        Using autoprefixer-rails 5.1.7
remote:        Using uglifier 2.7.0
remote:        Using net-sftp 2.1.2
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.3.0
remote:        Using figaro 1.1.0
remote:        Using sys-uname 0.9.0
remote:        Using haml 4.0.6
remote:        Using sprockets 2.12.3
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using unicorn 4.8.3
remote:        Using therubyracer 0.12.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.0
remote:        Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.3
remote:        Using mini_magick 3.8.0
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.1
remote:        Using imagemagick-binaries 6.8.7.5.1
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.1
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.3
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.0
remote:        Using climate_control 0.0.3
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.2.8
remote:        Using pundit 0.3.0
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.5
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.0
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.0
remote:        Using carrierwave 0.10.0
remote:        Using cocaine 0.5.7
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.0
remote:        Using polyamorous 1.1.0
remote:        Using carrierwave-dropbox 1.2.1
remote:        Using carrierwave-ftp 0.2.8
remote:        Using paperclip 4.3.0
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.0
remote:        Using paperclip-dropbox 1.3.2
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.0
remote:        Using railties 4.2.0
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 2.2.4
remote:        Using kaminari 0.16.3
remote:        Using ransack 1.6.3
remote:        Using simple_form 3.1.0
remote:        Using mail_form 1.5.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
remote:        Using responders 2.1.0
remote:        Using font-awesome-rails 4.3.0.0
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.1
remote:        Using lightbox2-rails 2.7.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.0
remote:        Using turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Using devise 3.4.1
remote:        Using jquery-datatables-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Using devise_invitable 1.4.1
remote:        Using upmin-admin 0.1.01
remote:        Bundle complete! 34 Gemfile dependencies, 92 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (1.07s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        Asset precompilation completed (5.58s)
remote:        Cleaning assets
remote:        Running: rake assets:clean
remote:
remote: ###### WARNING:
remote:        No Procfile detected, using the default web server (webrick)
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-default-web-server
remote:
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> (none)
remote:        Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
remote:
   remote: -----> Compressing... done, 155.5MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v123
remote:        https://app-name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
   remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
   To https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
6cb4846..275460b  master -> master
```

Comment: are you sure that your push to heroku after the reset was successful?
you probably have to force it since your local will be behind heroku master.

Comment: yes i tried git push --force heroku master but no luck

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting any error

Answer (score 1):

Restart your heroku app and check again. Here is the command

```
heroku restart -a app_name
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Please check the output now.

Answer (score 1):

> Later I switched back to previous commit using
>
> ```
> git reset --head Head^1
> ```

Since you've rewrote history, a normal push won't be accepted as it is not a fast forward.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Force push your current branch:

   ```
   $ git push -f heroku master
   ```
2. If all what you want is to have the previous live version back, run a rollback:

   ```
   $ heroku rollback
   ```

Comment: I've tried rolling back. My app is current stuck on v73.. If I roll back to any version greater than v73, it has no effect. But when I rolled back to v70, it made the changes to my app. Strange :\

Comment: You can't rollback to a version higher than your current one, it's simply not possible. Whenever you roll back, a new release gets created that is exactly the same as the one you rolled back. E.g. when you're at `v10` and rollback to `v9`, a new release `v11` is created that is the same snapshot as `v9`. The number is always incrementing in order to maintain a linear history.